# Swift: Action if the user accepted or rejected notifications

Tags: ios, swift, nsusernotification

I'm using the following code to request push and local notification permission:

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings( types:  [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil )

application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I need to wait for the user to either accept or decline the notifications before I take an action. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See the documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Apple has since deprecated the answer I've given below. Please see @ergunkocak's answer

When the user has either granted or denied permissions, the callback method in the app delegate is `application(_:didRegister:)` which is the method you should use for taking specific actions based on the user's chosen permission settings. I suggest reading the documentation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623022-application)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 in AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    // Check here
}
```